# How to get value in JSON array Using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

i want to know select value in JSON array.

my JSON is

```
{
  "meta": {
    "is_end": true,
    "total_count": 1,
    "pageable_count": 1
  },
  "documents": [
    {
      "road_address": {
        "undergroun_yn": "N",
        "road_name": "충대로",
        "underground_yn": "N",
        "region_2depth_name": "청주시 서원구",
        "zone_no": "28644",
        "sub_building_no": "",
        "region_3depth_name": "개신동",
        "main_building_no": "1",
        "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 충대로 1",
        "y": "36.63003935314667",
        "x": "127.45479196889647",
        "region_1depth_name": "충북",
        "building_name": "충북대학교"
      },
      "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 충대로 1",
      "address": {
        "b_code": "4311210900",
        "region_3depth_h_name": "성화.개신.죽림동",
        "main_address_no": "12",
        "h_code": "4311259000",
        "region_2depth_name": "청주시 서원구",
        "main_adderss_no": "12",
        "sub_address_no": "",
        "region_3depth_name": "개신동",
        "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 개신동 12",
        "y": "36.6284039605616",
        "x": "127.45921419389084",
        "mountain_yn": "N",
        "zip_code": "361763",
        "region_1depth_name": "충북",
        "sub_adderss_no": ""
      },
      "y": "36.63003935314667",
      "x": "127.45479196889647",
      "address_type": "ROAD_ADDR"
    }
  ]
}
```

but, this code error is occurred that say "**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object"**
so, i try to solve them and search many way.
i don't using a part of 'meta' only using 'documents' in JSON.
than, i write the java code.
my original code is

```
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(html.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject rootObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();


        JsonObject element = rootObj.get("documents").getAsJsonObject();
        String y = element.getAsJsonObject().get("x").toString();
        String x = element.getAsJsonObject().get("y").toString();

        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(html.toString());
        return html.toString();
```

and i knew "documents" is JSON array so, i revise my code.
my revised java code is

```
    JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(html.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject rootObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    String y = rootObj.getAsJsonArray().get(Integer.parseInt("x")).toString();
    String x = rootObj.getAsJsonArray().get(Integer.parseInt("y")).toString();

        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(html.toString());
        return html.toString();
```

but also error is occurred that say "**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array**"
i want to get result like

```
{
"documents": [
        {
          "road_address": {
            "undergroun_yn": "N",
            "road_name": "충대로",
            "underground_yn": "N",
            "region_2depth_name": "청주시 서원구",
            "zone_no": "28644",
            "sub_building_no": "",
            "region_3depth_name": "개신동",
            "main_building_no": "1",
            "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 충대로 1",
            "y": "36.63003935314667",
            "x": "127.45479196889647",
            "region_1depth_name": "충북",
            "building_name": "충북대학교"
          },
          "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 충대로 1",
          "address": {
            "b_code": "4311210900",
            "region_3depth_h_name": "성화.개신.죽림동",
            "main_address_no": "12",
            "h_code": "4311259000",
            "region_2depth_name": "청주시 서원구",
            "main_adderss_no": "12",
            "sub_address_no": "",
            "region_3depth_name": "개신동",
            "address_name": "충북 청주시 서원구 개신동 12",
            "y": "36.6284039605616",
            "x": "127.45921419389084",
            "mountain_yn": "N",
            "zip_code": "361763",
            "region_1depth_name": "충북",
            "sub_adderss_no": ""
          },
          "y": "36.63003935314667",
          "x": "127.45479196889647",
          "address_type": "ROAD_ADDR"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

and get key "x","y" and those values 
but, the error is continously occured.
how to solve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate through JSONArray to find JSONObject and then read x and y values.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(html.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject rootObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray documents = (JsonArray) rootObj.get("documents");
Iterator < JsonElement > itr = documents.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
 JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) itr.next();
 double x = jsonObject.getDouble("x");
 double y = jsonObject.getDouble("y");
}
```

Comment: thanks! i solve them!! 
but, just revise your code.
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(html.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject rootObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray documents = (JsonArray) rootObj.get("documents");
        Iterator<JsonElement> itr = documents.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject= (JsonObject) itr.next();
            JsonElement x = jsonObject.get("x");
            JsonElement y = jsonObject.get("y");
        }